# Adicionar parametros dinamicamente em uma função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, testes, argumento

Galera, tudo bem?

Estou tentando criar uma função(chamarei de executar) que receba como parâmetro outra função(chamarei de palavra), uma lista de objetos e uma lista de atributos para serem acessados nos objetos da lista.

Esta função "executar" ira executar a função que ela receber como parâmetro, mas como eu não sei quais são os parâmetros que devo passar na função que recebo em "executar", quero uma forma genérica de passar os parâmetros...

Segue código de exemplo:

```
//Lista com os parametros que quero pegar do objeto
  var listKeyParam = ["nome", "idade", "altura"];

  //Lista de objetos
  var objs = [
    { nome: "Anderson", idade: "21", altura: "1.85" },
    { nome: "Ranger", idade: "18", altura: "1.85" },
    { nome: "Renan", idade: "21", altura: "1.85" },
    { nome: "Guto", idade: "70", altura: "2.15" }
  ];

  //Funcao generica testar o recebimento dos parametros
  function palavra(nome,idade,altura) {
    console.log("nome => ",nome);
    console.log("idade => ",idade);
    console.log("altura => ", altura);
  }

  //Funcao que deve receber uma funcao como parametro, 
  //uma lista de objetos e a lista com os atributos que devem ser pegos dos objetos
  function executar(funcao, objs, listKeyParam) {

    objs.forEach((item, index) => {
      let argumentsFunc =[]
      $.each(item,(paramKey,paramValue) => {
        if(listKeyParam.includes(paramKey)) argumentsFunc.push(paramValue);
      });
      funcao(arguments = argumentsFunc);
    });


  }

  //Executando funcao
  executar(palavra, objs , listKeyParam);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como não conheço o contexto do seu projeto apenas alterei um pouco seu código para passar os parâmetros de forma genérica, como você citou. Basicamente para cada item o Array `objs` eu procuro as propriedades dentro do item que estão no array `listKeyParam` e crio um array com estes valores que ficam armazenados na variável `argumentos`. Depois utilizo o spread operator para passá-los como parâmetro:

```js
//Lista com os parametros que quero pegar do objeto
var listKeyParam = ["nome", "idade", "altura"];

  //Lista de objetos
var objs = [
  { nome: "Anderson", idade: "21", altura: "1.85" },
  { nome: "Ranger", idade: "18", altura: "1.85" },
  { nome: "Renan", idade: "21", altura: "1.85" },
  { nome: "Guto", idade: "70", altura: "2.15" }
];

// Funcao generica testar o recebimento dos parametros
function palavra(nome, idade, altura) {
  console.log("nome => ", nome);
  console.log("idade => ", idade);
  console.log("altura => ", altura);
}

// Funcao que deve receber uma funcao como parametro, 
// uma lista de objetos e a lista com os atributos que devem ser pegos dos objetos
function executar(funcao, objs, listKeyParam) {
  objs.forEach(item => {
    const argumentos = listKeyParam
      .filter(key => !!item[key])
      .map(key => item[key]);
      
    funcao(...argumentos);
  });
}

// Executando funcao
executar(palavra, objs , listKeyParam);
```

Espero que te ajude ;)

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Era exatamente isso que eu estava querendo \õ/
Só não voto na tua resposta pq tenho menos de 15 pontos de reputação huahuahuhua

Comment: @AndersonDuarte muito obrigado, vlw ;)